# Does the rejection tag cover candidates rejecting a job offer?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [rejection](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rejection) tag with 20-odd questions which for the most part seems to cover the typical scenario of a hiring manager rejecting a candidate for a job. But **should this tag also include questions from the other side**, i.e. a job candidate replying to the hiring manager to reject a job offer?

Comment: Unless we have a specific case where that is causing a problem, and/or a better tag suggestion.

Comment: @keshlam That's pretty much what I thought. Mind adding that as an answer?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not wild about the judgemental tone of "rejection", though, and it's begging to be used by someone heartbroken by a workplace relationship... So I'd actually rather fix the tag for clarity. I don't have a good suggestion , though.

Comment: You could turn it into "offer-rejection" to avoid that but I'm not a fan of lengthening tags when there's no real need to do so. If someone abuses the tag in the scenario you give it's just up to the community to fix the tags. I actually expected we'd have an 'office-romance' tag but apparently we don't.

Comment: "But should this tag also include questions from the other side," - sure. No reason to create yet another tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not?  Any rejection involves a rejector and a rejectee, so unless the concerns are so different that they demand separate tags, let's just use one.

We should create a tag when a category of question has its own cohesion (this grouping matters) and when it would be lost in the larger tag that would otherwise be used.  It doesn't sound like we're there yet with this tag; if that changes later, we can retag some questions.